# How can I set up Eclipse to edit Perl without the runtime checking?

Tags: perl, eclipse, text-editor

I'm working on a project that include both Java (on the client side) and Perl (on the server side), and I would really like to use Eclipse to edit my Perl scripts instead of going to another editor. I've tried to use the [EPIC plugin](http://www.epic-ide.org/). However, I have no way of setting up a run environment for these scripts on my local machine, so the plugin displays all kinds of errors related to missing libraries and other external dependencies.

I just want a text editor with nice syntax highlighting for Perl. Any suggestions? Any way that you can turn off the runtime error checking when using the EPIC plugin? I wasn't able to find anything with a quick search.

Comment: Why can't you set up a development environment locally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't a setting, per se, in the workbench. It's a per-project setting.

While in your Perl project, select Project->Properties. In that dialog, click on "Builders". You probably have just the one-- "Perl Auto Builder". De-select it and click "Ok".

Unfortunately, you'll have to do this for each separate Perl project.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't indicate your OS. Try [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/) - it is cross-platform. It can be installed with the CPAN shell (if you use [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) on Windows, you will need at least the version from October). Padre is still rapidly evolving, but already has support for Perl 5 and 6 (6 will require a plugin). HTML, JavaScript and CSS (also with plugins). Many other plugins are already written, for example for Perl::Critic.

Comment: It's only cross-platform if you can get Wx to compile, and that's not often an easy task.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Perlipse](http://code.google.com/p/perlipse/), which appears to be an [active](http://perlipse.blogspot.com/) project.

Comment: I had not heard of Perlipse. Thanks for the tip. I installed it and tried it out, but I got all kindof exceptions. My impression was that it was not ready for prime time. Googling the exception I got, I found this thread: http://www.poweredbypulse.com/forums/showthread.php?t=846

Answer (score 0):

[Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) is a great text editor for Perl.
`cperl-mode` has the best Perl syntax highlighting support of any
editor (even Padre), and Emacs should meet all of your editing needs.
It is easily scriptable, and there are thousands of extensions
available for it.  (Some even make support for Perl better, like [Stylish::REPL](http://github.com/jrockway/stylish).)

Comment: Yes, downmod legitimate suggestions!  Regardless of your personal
tastes, vim and emacs are the most popular perl editors.

Comment: yeah... I find EPIC plugin really good! I'd like like someone to show me how can vim and emacs achieve what eclipse does...

Answer (score 0):

Use `EditPlus`, simplest editor for syntax highlighting. Works well for `Perl`.