# How to Stop Perl EPIC eclipse plugin showing errors

Tags: eclipse, perl

My eclipse tries to compile/build Perl files in my Java project and fails. I installed Perl EPIC just for syntax colouring, how can I get it to ignore errors?

I tried going into Project->Properties->Builders, and uncheck Perl Epic, this didn't change anything.

I'm using Eclipse :Helios Service Release 1
Build id: 20100917-0705
On Windows XP

I have basically the same issue as this question, 
[How can I set up Eclipse to edit Perl without the runtime checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547237/how-can-i-set-up-eclipse-to-edit-perl-without-)

Comment: having the exact same problem here with Indigo. It simply complains of missing libraries, even when all validators and builders are disabled for the project. Annoying thing.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into similar issue for quite some time too. Apparently the Epic Perl plugin goes wildly checking anything/folder/file it finds inside the project, so like mine where I have config files, data directories, it goes inside and tries to validate "perl stuff", which evidently is an annoyance: the error log view displays a lot of useless information.

Did you try to uncheck the "Perl Auto Builder" ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not parsing this sentence in the context of your question: "My eclipse tries to compile/build perl files in my java project and fails."

Are you saying that you are running perl as a java project, and getting the inevitable error message because it is not java? Just wondering why you don't want to have your perl program set up as a perl project possibly referenced by your java project, assuming that that is what you are trying to do.

Generally, when I set up a perl project, I edit its properties and set its includes to match the current directory or local module paths. Assuming that there are self-written modules I must call, and they are not located on this machine (e.g. I wouldn't have FOO::smb on a windows machine -- it makes no sense. When I am developing for linux, I will put all my functions in there for convenience's sake)

In that case, I create a FOO directory in the workspace, and create a dummy FOO::smb module with however many stub functions in it to get me going and let my syntax highlighting and error checkign do their proper jobs for me. If I write dummy subs to match the real modules well enough, I can debug my scripts somewhat before uploading them. I figure that I should be well enough aware of what they are supposed to do anyway.

I will go so far as to dummy out CPAN modules assuming that installing them on my development workstation makes no sense or is impossible. Highlighting and syntax checking are both invaluable tools, and finding a way to make both of them work saves my sanity.

Comment: "Are you saying that you are running perl as a java project, and getting the inevitable error message because it is not java?" no in my java projects there are some perl files. I don't want to run them or anything, just syntax highlighting. But Perl Epic tries to parse them and detects errors (missing libraries etc). I'd like it to stop doing that