# Perl syntax checking in Eclipse, ignore missing modules

Tags: eclipse, perl, syntax

When I turn on syntax checking for Perl in Eclipse (with `EPIC` plugin), it shows errors in `use` directives, because I edit Perl remotely (through FTP with `Remote Systems Explorer` plugin) and some modules available on the remote FTP server are not available on my local machine.

Can Perl syntax checking be restricted not to show an error in the case of a missing module?

If no, I'd disable Perl syntax checking completely. By the way, how to do this?

Comment: I don't know specifically how EPIC works, but if it uses something like `perl -c` (Perl's built-in syntax check) then no. This is because how Perl code is parsed depends on what modules are loaded. Yes, modules can affect how the syntax of the caller code is interpreted!

Comment: @tobyinc, It uses PPI

Answer (score 2):

From my googling, I don't think there is a way to do this. The best workaround seems to be creating dummy modules to make the errors go away. I've found 2 sources that recommended the use of dummy modules for this purpose; an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5465694/2534803) on Stack Overflow and a [forum post](http://sourceforge.net/p/e-p-i-c/discussion/258688/thread/2ef133a3/) on Source Forge.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access to remote server than you can mount your lib directory from remote server to your local machine, for example if you're using linux you can do this with [sshfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) or if you're Windows user than use [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29).

Now go to project properties in Eclipse and in `Perl Include Path` section add your path to previously mounted directory.
[image]

Comment: That will only work if it doesn't have any arch-specific component. Better to install the modules locally (if possible) or creating a directory with empty .pm files included as you specified (if not possible). Saves you from setting up file servers on the remote system, something he might not even be able to do.